# Removing class on one div when other is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Following is my HTML,

```
 <div class="container">
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li class="nb-link"><a>Home</a></li>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a>CBSE</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>10th Standard</li>
        <li>12th Standard</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a>Engineering</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>JEE - Main</li>
        <li>JEE - Advanced</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I have 2 dropdowns . When I click one, it comes down. But when I click another, even that comes down without closing the previous one . This creates an overlap. The way I'm handling this using JS is as follows

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

      if ($this.children('.dropdown-menu').hasClass('open')) {
        $this.removeClass('active');
        $('.navbar').$this.children('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('open');
        $this.children('.dropdown-menu').fadeOut("fast");
      } 


        else {
          $this.addClass('active');
          $this.children('.dropdown-menu').addClass('open');
          $this.children('.dropdown-menu').fadeIn("fast");
        }

    });

});
```

How can I achieve a functionality using JS such that the previous dropdown closes when I click a new dropdown ? Also, the dropdowns should close when anywhere on the page is clicked ?

Comment: How about just using a `select` element, it does everything you want and more

Comment: @adeneo Good point but a select element isn't really customizable regarding styling

Comment: i have actually already written the stylesheet. dont want to touch that .

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you could provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @A.Wolff - Yeah, I suppose styled lists are more appealing in some cases. The issue is quite easily solved by just doing something like `$('.dropdown').not(this).hide()` when a dropdown is shown

Comment: fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/50sjx6xo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.dropdown').not($this).removeClass('active')
        $('.dropdown-menu').not($this.find('.dropdown-menu')).removeClass('open');
        $this.toggleClass('active');
        $this.find('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/50sjx6xo/1/)

this is a function you can use if selectors is not target

```
// function for if selectors not target
function actionwindowclick(e , selector , action){
            if (!$(selector).is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
                && $(selector).has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
            {
            action();
        }
}
```

and you can use it in window click event like this

```
$(window).on('click', function(e){
     actionwindowclick(e , ".dropdown , .dropdown-menu" , function(){
         $('.dropdown').removeClass('active')
         $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('open');
     });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/50sjx6xo/4/)

> Note: I think you may need to
>   [**event.stopPropagation()**](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)
>   while you trying to click on .dropdown-menu itself

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation()
});
```

Comment: hey ! thanks it works . but i also need a functionality where when you click anywhere on the screen and if the dropdown is open, then it will close !

Comment: @saru95 You're welcome .. but please don't miss any part from my answer .. it will help you if you have another problem specially e.stopPropagation()  .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score -1):

Try:
    `$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.dropdown').click(function() {

            var $this = $(this);

            $this.children('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('open');

            if ($this.children('.dropdown-menu').hasClass('open')) {

                $this.removeClass('active');

                $this.children('.dropdown-menu').fadeOut("fast");

            }

            else {

                $this.addClass('active');

                $this.children('.dropdown-menu').fadeIn("fast");

            }

        });

    });`